# Python - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when reading from .rtf file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am getting:

```
Python - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I want to read from file. My code is:

```
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
      outfile.write(b)
      while True:
        buf = infile.read(1024)
        if not buf:
            break
        outfile.write(cipher.update(buf)) 
      outfile.write( cipher.final() )  
      outfile.close()
    infile.close()
```

I am getting error in `with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:` line.

```
infile= c:\\users\\cipher~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\CCB\\16977740fbd0f8491aca818446b9d6c703a2b14d\\allpolicies.rtf


out_filename= D:\\one.rtf
```

I am generating infile location as tempfile.gettempdir() + os.sep +"CCB" , then using hash function for next folder generation. Then placing file in that location.

I tried with `os.sep` also but it didn't work. Same code working fine with .txt file.

Comment: Try running the console with administrator privileges.

Comment: unrelated: remove `.close()` calls (`with`-statements will call `.close()` automatically)